# Create elements and independently scroll them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm not very familiar with this sort of web development.

Basically what I am trying to do is have a button (or keyboard key) which makes an image appear and then scroll across the screen and disappear..

Scenario: The Button(key) is pressed 10 times, 1 time every second.

10 images are appear and each one scrolls across the screens width and then disappears.

How am I able to do this?

The effect I would like to get is quite similar to the Konami code Easter egg used on the http://www.vogue.co.uk/ website.

I'm guessing it's JavaScript or similar but I don't know how to write it. Neither do I know scripting in jQuery.

Comment: It should be possible with jQuery,you might look at http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ like http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(function () {
    var images = [
        'http://placehold.it/100x100',
        'http://placehold.it/150x150',
        'http://placehold.it/200x250',
        'http://placehold.it/200x200'];
    var index = 0;
    $(document).on('keypress', function (event) {
        var c = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
        if(c === 'a') {
            var image = images[index];
            console.log(image);
            index = (index + 1) % images.length;
            $('<img style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0" src="' + image + '"/>')
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .animate({right: '200%'}, 2000, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
        }
    })
});
```

Press the 'a' key to make the images in the array slide from the right. Edit the array to use your images. You will need to include jQuery in your project.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/tD4FG/

Comment: Than you so much. Exactly what I needed.
Nice Work!

Comment: I'll do that now.

On a slightly different point though, how exactly would I be able to integrate this to run only when it has been called. So it becomes "active" per se once it has been run by another javascript.

Comment: @Stealthbird97 Just wrap the whole thing in a function and call that function when you need to. Just make sure you only execute the above code once.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something. Not the cleanest it could be but works:

Heres the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>         
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>       
           <script src="popUpButton.js"></script>   
        </head>

        <body> 
                <div id="ToolBar" class="ToolbarDiv">
                <button onclick="popUpButton()" type="button">ButtonOne</button>
                </div>                            
        </body> 
</html>
```

And here is the javascript function:

```
function popUpButton() {
        var popUpB = document.createElement('div');
        popUpB.className = 'ButtonClass';
        popUpB.id = 'ButtonID';
        var message = document.createElement('img');
        message.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
        popUpB.appendChild(message);                                           
        document.body.appendChild(popUpB);

        $("img").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "+=1000px",
        }, 3000 );
}
```

Hope that is what you need.